# Multiple Regression using R

Tags: r, regression

Good morning everyone! I am learning R but I'm facing more than one difficulty by doing this!
I have this problem:
Using the file wm1.txt in the package alr3, I have to estimate the parameters of this model:
 E(Y|X=x) = beta_0 + beta_1 x + beta_2 x^2

...the problem is: how can I find beta2? I know that it is not  linear function and I also could find b1 and b2 but now that I see this b2 I am lost.. What commands should I use?

Thanks

Comment: *I also could find b0 and b1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `I` operator to inhibit interpretation of `x^2` in your regression formula:

```
library(alr3)
data(wm1)
lm(RSpd ~ CSpd + I(CSpd^2), data= wm1)
```

Output:

```
> lm(RSpd ~ CSpd + I(CSpd^2), data= wm1)

Call:
lm(formula = RSpd ~ CSpd + I(CSpd^2), data = wm1)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         CSpd    I(CSpd^2)  
   1.073476     0.729228     0.001331
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. So, it is not necessary to use the nls function?

Comment: There is nothing nonlinear about this regression equation. Recall that the definition of nonlinear regression is nonlinear in _parameters_ not nonlinear in _covariates_.

Comment: Oh yes.. you are right! I've said so because I've also the case where I have to find b2 starting from this function:
E(Y|X=x) = beta_0 + beta_1 log(x) + beta_2 log(x)^2
 in this case, we have a nonlinear function so I have to use nls right?

Comment: Nope, still not a nonlinear regression equation. As I said, nonlinear in parameters (the relationship between the CEF and the parameters must be nonlinear). For example, E(Y|X) = exp(b0 + b1*X) is a nonlinear regression equation.

Comment: Sorry and thanks for the patience.. I will try till the moment I'll learn it for good :)) ..R is not my forte!